# Embed private google slides publicly with access token

Tags: google-drive-api, google-slides-api

I want to create a website where users can see private google slides after logging in into my website. I will have the access token for the account which holds the ownership of those private files.

What I want to do is display the private files to my website users after they log in.

Right now I can display the private files by downloading them via an API and display it in a custom pdf viewer with pdf.js but I want to know is if  there is any way to display private presentations with Google's embedded viewer maybe with some type of token (I don't want to force the user to sign in to their Google account. Also, note that I have an access token for those files).

Comment: Try using a service account that act as you (a user that has access to the file) to silently authorize your request then get the `webViewLink` and place it in an iframe and that should do the trick. Following this would create a web view of a file inside your site.